# Inherit rotation for Bendy Bone ends

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

[image]I have a bendy bone rig with 5 bones.

This rig is to animate a dancing soft drink tin, to music via MIDI (using TouchOSC from my iPad in real-time, and the AddRoutes 0.32 add-on from [www.jpfep.net](http://www.jpfep.net)). I’m using Blender 2.83 because the python changes after that version broke the add-on and I like “digital puppeteering” in real-time via MIDI.

My rig has control bones are at beginning, end and middle with 8 segment bones between. The control bones inherit the position of circle empties via copy position constraint and move just fine. However the bone ends and middle won’t rotate with copy rotation constraint linked to the same circle empties.

What am I missing here? Something tells me i’ve been here before and solved it but I can’t remember how.

There must be a way to give rotation to bendy bone ends in object mode? I intend to animate multiple axis (in this case x and y - forward and sideways rotation) to all 3 rircle in real-time.
[image: in the attached image you can see the circle rig controls that control the bendy-bone rig at it top,middle and base]I animate in real-time using auto-key this way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi. This question is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Support your description with [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.